# Passing Streams in service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm curious if anybody has any experience with passing streams in Service Fabric. Or something similar. I have a need to expose some large data streams from various Actors. DataContract serializing a byte[] probably isn't the best idea.

Basically, I would like something that looks like a method on my Actor, that returns to the client something that it can read from.

Answer (score 1):

Since communication between actors might/will span multiple machines it might be better to store the stream as a blob in Azure Storage and send the filename to the target actor instead. The target actor can then read from the file, process it and send back a result either directly as the return type (if the response is a regular datatype or small object) or store another file with the response and return the new filename.